# Does the Amplified (classic) give a trustworthy version of Mark 4:23-25?

Tags: translation-philosophy, mark

Here is the passage...

**Mark 4:23-25** ([AMP Classic Edition](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%204%3A23-25&version=AMPC))

> 23 If any man has ears to hear, let him be listening and let him
>   perceive and comprehend.
>
> 24 And He said to them, Be careful what you are hearing. The measure
>   [of thought and study] you give [to the truth you hear] will be
>   the measure [of virtue and knowledge] that comes back to you—and
>   more [besides] will be given to you who hear.
>
> 25 For to him who has will more be given; and from him who has
>   nothing, even what he has will be taken away [by force],

It seems to go way beyond the translation provided by other versions of the Bible.

I am a novice of exegesis. What is the best way to approach this version when studying this Bible passage?

Comment: The Amplified Bible in general is not that great a translation. Translation is a tricky process, but almost all translators separate the purpose of conveying the meaning of the Bible text in another language from explaining and commentating on the text, but the Amplified Bible mixes those up together.

Comment: Hello Fenella, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us! If you haven't done it already, please make sure to take our tour to see how we are a little different than other sites you may know. Thanks! hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This is a great question. If reviewers have an objection, let us consider rephrasing the title because "how to view different Bible translations" is very relevant to hermeneutics and this is a genuinely curious person asking the best way we should expect.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about "what to expect from a Bible translation". So, we need to start with a contrast.

First and for reference, consider another translation, one of the best for being most literal...

**Mark 4:23-25** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%204%3A23-25&version=NASB))

> 23 If anyone has ears to hear, let him hear.” 24 And He was saying to them, “Take care what you listen to. By your standard of measure it will be measured to you; and more will be given you besides. 25 For whoever has, to him more shall be given; and whoever does not have, even what he has shall be taken away from him.”

The Amplified Bible specifically adds enormous numbers of words on purpose. You could call this "clarity via synonyms". This is the reason people use it in Bible study specifically.

Greek and Hebrew verbs often carry much more meaning than verbs in English or other languages. So, the added words can also clarify the nature of the verbs, such as "be listening" from v23 to emphasize a continuous, ongoing action in the present tense.

When it comes to measuring accuracy of the Amplified, simply trim out words that repeat or are unnecessary for a normal sentence. Then, compare that to another translation, such as the ESV or the NASB. Once you do that, the Amplified isn't really that different. So, is it trustworthy? Yes.

Consider this reduction: (shortening long words, removing redundant synonyms, and removing additions [in brackets])

*Mark 4:23-25 (Amplified Classic Edition)* (words removed)

> 23 If any man has ears to hear, let him listen.
>
> 24 And He said to them, Be careful what you hear. The measure
>   you give will be the measure that comes back to you—and more will be given to you who hear.
>
> 25 For to him who has will more be given; and from him who has
>   nothing, even what he has will be taken away,

That isn't very different from the NASB (above).

Being familiar with Greek, I know that most of what was cut out was a connotation of the verb forms and definitions in Greek.

### Summary

Can the Amplified Bible be trusted? Yes, when used for its purpose which is to "amplify" or "elaborate". The purpose of the Amplified Bible is to add one more opinion to the mix when doing "Bible study via multiple translations".

Usually, get a literal translation like the NASB to look up words, the ESV or NLT for a natural flow, The Message for a more "down to earth" phrasing, and the Amplified to add clarity by words. This is usually called a "parallel Bible study". This is one reason the Amplified Bible would go great in a "parallel Bible" if you decide to get one.

Comment: The falsehoods of people who are not chosen will remain, while the chosen one’s will have them removed, in other words.